OpenXML find paragprah style numbering
TL;DR
I have an application that generates legal contracts in a Word document, a contract has multiple clauses and each clause has a numbering style. The generation itself consists of selecting and reordering clauses from a catalog.
Clauses may reference others by number,ex.: "[...] according to Clause 1.3.1 above is [...]".
The problem is since the numbering is autogenerated and managed by the word document it self and I have no idea which clauses are selected how do I find the clause section number?

Detailed
The numbering is managed by the Word document style itself when I generate the document I simply create a paragraph by providing the style and the text content.
I surround each paragraph with a BookmarkStart and a BookmarkEnd, so I can easily create a hyperlink to the bookmark but without the number itself, it has no practical use. Imagine reading a contract that references other clauses and you have to search through the whole contract to find them.
I've tried to obtain the Numbering Styles but to no avail. As the picture above shows the Clauses 1.3 might change. Can I do this with OpenXml, or using word macros?

If you are generating using openxml, but can open the document using the Word object model after that, try this: insert the XML for the REF field, leave the result text empty, insert the XML for the referenced bookmark in the relevant Clause paragraph. Then open the document in Word and use VBA to find and update the relevant field codes. Perhaps use a naming convention if you want to ensure that you update only those Ref fields.

Otherwise, the problem is that the actual number of the Clause is not stored in the XML - it's generated dynamically from the numbering styles stored in the document. SO your XML generation code would have to replicate everything Word does, including noticing when numbering restarts, that kind of thing. That's probably not a trivial problem to solve.

You might be able to do it using SEQ fields and bookmarks. Word's automatic paragraph numbering is not simple. See https://superuser.com/questions/1609025/importing-numbered-paragraph-styles-in-word/1609033#1609033 It can be difficult to set it up properly in Word directly.

@CharlesKenyon thank you for your answer, I have figured it out. I will make sure I post the strategy I adopted.

@jonsson Thanks for the strategy, like I mentioned in the previous comment I have discovered another strategy and will post it as soon as I can.
